# Question about process access privilege

Tags: windows, winapi, process, createprocess, openprocess

I got the following scenario:

Process A create process B, and then B try to get a handle of A with OpenProcess(). I want B to have PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS rights to A.

How should I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is for the parent to avoid the child having to call OpenProcess at all. Instead, have the parent retrieve a handle to itself (which will automatically have all access) and then call DuplicateHandle with bInheritHandle = true. Then when it creates process B, that handle (with full access to process A) will already be open in the child. Process A simply has to pass the handle to process B, and process B can use it.